# Html ActionLink not posting to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, form-submit

I am trying to submit to a controller action method by using Html.ActionLink in my view. I am doing this as non-ajax submit because the return type of my action is FileContentResult (thanks to @Darin for this info). However, my action link is not posting my view to Action Method. Below is my code

**View's Code (Partial view)**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveFile", "ui", new { htmlResult="asdf"})
```

Here, UI is controller name, SaveFile is method name.

**Controller method**

```
public FileContentResult SaveFile(string htmlString)
        {
...
...

pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(html);


    var cd = new ContentDisposition

    {
        FileName = "MyFile.pdf",
        Inline = false
    };

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");

}
```

When I hit the same URL from browser address bar, then it is hit and also returns the pdf file with no issues. Same this is not happening through action link. I also tried putting the action link inside @using Html.BeginForm().... but no use.

Can you please tell me where I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post how is the generated link looks like if you view the html source?

Comment: @nemesv: Here it is<a href="/ui/SaveFile?Length=2" htmlresult="asdf">Save</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` has a lots of overloads and it's very easy to use the wrong one. You are currently using the [(String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29) overload which treats your third argument `"ui"` this route values which leads to a wrongly generated link.

Use this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29) instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", //Link text
                 "SaveFile", // Action Name
                 "ui", // Controller name
                 new { htmlResult="asdf"}, //Route values
                 null /* html attributes */)
```

Comment: After implementing above overload, here is the link generated
<a href="/ui/SaveFile?htmlResult=asdf">
Still it is not working

Comment: Oh.. its working now in my main page! When I put it in partial view, it does not work.

Comment: Because I am displaying the partial view as modal dialog using JQuery dialog. If I make it modal=false then it works. Thanks for your solution any way. It was correct.

Comment: @AnilSoman I glad that your problem is solved. Maybe you should consider to accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Sure will do it. I was just trying to resolve the problem of modal dialog. :)